# Parsing HTML with OCaml

Tags: html, ocaml

I'm looking for a library to parse HTML files in OCaml.
Basically the equivalent of Jsoup/Beautiful Soup.
The main requirement is being able to query the DOM with CSS selectors.
Something in the form of

```
page.fetch("http://www.url.com")
page.find("#tag")
```

Comment: what about https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-cow

Comment: thanks. i found that but it seems like their HTML support isn't that robust. "you may hit various limitations with HTML input parsing. We hope to solve this before Cow 1.0, but it isn't there yet..."

Comment: `ocamlnet` has a way to parse HTML, although I don't know if it has the selector support.

Comment: I wanted  to use `ocamlnet` for a personal project but there is no selector support ..

Comment: I believe the parser in OCamlnet is rather robust.  It indeed does not have selector support but you can implement that with a few recursive functions on the parsed tree.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a need for something like this recently, so after seeing this question and reading the recommendations in the comments, I wrote a library "[Lambda Soup](https://github.com/aantron/lambda-soup)" over the weekend for fun.

You will want to use a library like ocurl or Cohttp to retrieve the actual HTML. After you have it, you can do

```
html |> parse $ "#tag"
```

to do what is asked in the question. For other possibilities and the full signature, see the [documentation](http://aantron.github.io/lambda-soup). You may want to look at the documentation [postprocessor](https://github.com/aantron/lambda-soup/blob/master/docs/postprocess.ml) or [tests](https://github.com/aantron/lambda-soup/blob/master/test/test.ml#L47) for a fairly thorough demonstration of usage and capabilities, including CSS support and extensions.

<s>Per comments, Lambda Soup uses Ocamlnet's HTML parser.</s> Lambda Soup uses [Markup.ml](https://github.com/aantron/markup.ml). Otherwise, it has no dependencies, except OUnit if you wish to run the tests. I'm happy for any feedback, including about modifying the interface (it is at an early stage) or discussions of adding an HTTP downloader to the library (which seems iffy because it greatly alters the scope of the library as it now is, but I am happy to hear arguments).

The license is BSD.

Comment: This looks great! Thanks so much for all your work. I'll definitely let you know if I have any remarks. I agree that adding HTTP download is redundant at this stage.